StackOverflowException on project startup in JetBrains Rider but not in Visual Studio 2022
I have a large .NET solution (~25 projects) that runs and debugs without any issues in Visual Studio 2022. Recently, I tried switching to JetBrains Rider (version 2024.3.2). However, when I attempt to start my main .NET API project in Rider, I immediately encounter an error while the project is starting up.
Error Message:
Target process has exited during evaluation of instance method System.Exception.get_Message() with actual parameters System.StackOverflowException. 
This may possibly happen due to StackOverflowException


This exception occurs right at startup and prevents the application from running. The exact same solution and configuration work perfectly fine in Visual Studio 2022.
What I’ve Tried:
Following the guidance in this JetBrains YouTrack issue.
Unchecking the Allow property evaluations and other implicit function calls setting in Rider’s debugger options.
Unfortunately, these attempts did not resolve the issue.
Additional Details:

IDE: JetBrains Rider 2024.3.2
IDE that works: Visual Studio 2022
.NET Version: .NET 8.0
OS: Sequoia 15.2

Question:
Has anyone encountered a similar StackOverflowException when starting a .NET API in Rider? If so, how did you resolve it? Are there additional Rider-specific debugger settings or known issues that I might need to consider?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Does the issue only happen with attaching the debugger?
If so, you could create a support ticket for it in IDE (Help | Contact Support), or create a new YouTrack issue to get quicker help.
